# Interworx website backup - in between angry client and angry host - Im the meat?

Tags: backup, cpanel, web-hosting

I have been contacted today by someone who is wanting to restore his website.

Long story short, host cancelled and deleted his account.  He has a backup from a few weeks ago which will do fine.  it is a interworx backup (i-worx).  I dont have access to interworx  control panel but I would like to extract the files and ftp them up to another host for this customer.

Can it be done without the interworx cpanel?  Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a compressed tar so you should be able to extract it and manually move over all the data.